# Xamarin.Forms custom entry renderer set entry scrollable on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a custom renderer for a Xamarin entry and I have added `this.Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;` inside of the OnElementChanged inside of the android renderer but I can not see a scroll bar.

I have done similar on the iOS side `this.Control.ScrollEnabled = true;` and it works.

Am I missing something? thank you

Android Custom renderer code

````
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

using NGT.Views.ReusableViews;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderedEditor), typeof(NGT.Droid.BorderedEditorRenderer))]

namespace NGT.Droid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Boardered editor renderer.
    /// </summary>
    public class BorderedEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BorderedEditorRenderer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">Context.</param>
        public BorderedEditorRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ons the element changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">E.</param>
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control != null)
            {
                this.Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;    
            }

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetCornerRadius(5);
                gd.SetStroke(2, Constants.AppBlue.ToAndroid());
                this.Control.Background = gd;
                this.Control.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done;

            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the custom renderer code.

Comment: @Que44 sorry, I have done that now :)

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `this.Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;`, does it stop at that line? (If not, may need to do this in `protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged` instead. Just an idea; not sure it makes sense.) Are there any relevant warnings or errors in VS Output pane?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve the breakpoint is hit and there are no warnings or errors coming out of the output. :D

Comment: I repeated your test - confirmed this is a bug. Added [open issue for Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14807). Unfortunately, I did not find any workaround.